# Retrieving table from QueryString ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I am creating a simple query to grab a row of data according to the ID that is held in a text box. However it is not retrieving information nor is it erroring.

I have a textbox in which is filled with a querystring parameter thats passed in the URL. This is working and showing the exact ID on the page.

I am using this to grab the rest of its information into the relevant fields.

***C#***

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            try
            {

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Recipe_Name, Recipe_Description, Recipe_Instructions FROM Recipe Where Recipe_ID= @recipeid", con);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@recipeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RecipeID.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    nameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                descriptionTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                instructionsTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

                dt.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

***ASP.NET***

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><asp:Label ID="RecipeID" runat="server" ><%=Request.QueryString["id"] %></asp:Label></h1>

        <asp:Label ID="nameTxt" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    </hgroup>

            <table style="width:926px">
              <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" > IMAGE </td>
                <td >
                    <asp:Panel ID="descriptionPnl" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="160px" Width="472px">
                        <asp:Label ID="descriptionTxt" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>
                  </td> 
              </tr>    
            </table>

    <h6> Step by Step Guide</h6>

            <table style="width:900px">
              <tr>
                <td >  
                    <asp:Panel ID="guidePnl" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="200px" Width="900px">
                        <asp:Label ID="instructionsTxt" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>
                  </td> 
              </tr>   
            </table>           

    </asp:Content>
```

Can anyone help me in the matter? Where am i going wrong and what do i need to add or change. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure you are familiar, that's the `+` sign in which you concatenate strings. In your case that's this horror: `Recipe_ID= '"+RecipeID.Text+"'"`. Now try entering the following text in the `RecipeID` field in your browser: `; DROP TABLE Recipe; --`. Ooopsy. Now read about `parametrized queries`. You can google it, I am sure you will get more than enough information. That is to say that you have far more serious problems to deal with first before talking about query strings and retrieving some values from them.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i simply added parametrized queries and 'oopsy' its still not working, so this isnt really a constructive conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not erroring because you catch all exceptions and do nothing with it.

Also, you're vulnerable to sql injection with that code (as rightly pointed out in the comments).

You should use a relative path to locate the database file (that will break when deployed) and you should put configuration info like that in the Web.config file.

Comment: How do i add a relative path?

Comment: That's a full, explicit path. Use Server.MapPath("~/[path to db relative to your Web application root folder]"); Looks like you should be reading tutorials on Web app development for an overview of configuration, parameter encoding and lots of other things. Hope you have fun, but be sure to get someone to check it out over on stack code review before releasing, the issues with the code above are numerous.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];
            RecipeID.Text = ID;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            try
            {

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Recipe_Name, Recipe_Description, Recipe_Instructions FROM Recipe Where Recipe_ID= @recipeid", con);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@recipeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RecipeID.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    nameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                descriptionTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                instructionsTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

                dt.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@recipeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString["id"];